# how to launch an app in UI Testing with openURL (swift)

Tags: swift, xcode-ui-testing

I have an app that opens using the "Open in..." menu from apps such as Mail or Dropbox for a specific document type. Is it possible to pass in the NSURL when the app is launched from UI Testing?
I've tried XCUIApplication().launchArguments but that's not triggering the open openURL of the app.